# Laravel, Use an external class in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I used many functions from class to be used in a controller and this is a normal way to prevent duplicate of the code, but I have a function that store distance in a model and use collection for pagination, this function works fine and return $stores variable in the controller to be used for pagination, now I need to put it in a class and call it from the controller, unfortunately it returns null value!!! how can I fix this issue? the same function in the controller works fine but if i put it in a class and called from controller will return null, please help me

[image]

Class:

```
public function getStoresDistance($allstores)
{
    $stores = collect([]);
    foreach (session('storeinfo') as $storeInfo) {
        $store = $allstores->find($storeInfo['id']);
        if ($store) {
            $store->distance = $storeInfo['distance'];
            $stores[] = $store;
            if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
                Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage = 25, $page = null, $options = []) {
                    $options['path'] = $options['path'] ?? request()->path();
                    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);

                    return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                        $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
                        $this->count(),
                        $perPage,
                        $page,
                        $options
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call from controller:

```
$allstores = Storeinfo::where('show', 'y')->get();
$findstores = Helper::getStoresDistance($allstores);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the function is common for multiple controllers, move it to a PHP trait. Traits are specifically designed for reusability purpose. You can then use that trait in your controller and call its function as you would your controller functions like so `$this->yourFunction()`. Below is how your code will look:

**Trait:**

```
trait StoresDistance
{
    public function storesDistance(){}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    use StoresDistance;

    public function getStoresDistance($allstores)
    {
         // some code
         $this->storesDistance();
         // some code
    }
}
```

Reference Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php